# Can't load my app on the Samsung galaxy prevail and I try settings and unkonw source

Tags: android

Can't load the app i made on the Samsung galaxy prevail and I try goning to settings and unkonw source but it still not showing up on the avd manager in eclispe and  i was try development USB debugging but that just have it chage the battey. it work on one of my friends evo

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need samsung adb drivers. Google the drivers or install samsung Kies and you will see your device in the "Select device to run on" dialog (when running the app in eclipse).